# The maximum number of file handles (ulimit -n) allowed for Domino is 4096

Tags: unix, ibm-domino

I have a setup with many Domino servers (installed mostly on UNIX).
From time to time on some servers we see such warnings

> [001555:000047-0000123123123123] 09/13/2020 12:18:35 PM  WARNING: The
> maximum number of file handles (ulimit -n) allowed for Domino is
> 32768. See IBM Lotus Tech Note 1221870 and set the allowable maximum to 60000.

I know how to change limit, but that is post-reaction on the warning, instead I would like to prevent such warnings/cases.

I'm looking for a way to check the current number of file handles for Domino and if it is not 60.000 send a notification to Administrator.

Right now I do not know how to verify current number of file handles for Domino.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd run `ulimit -n`. Of course as the user your Domino is running under. I'm sure you have a monitoring system in place where you can add this check.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice: use the [Start-Stop](https://www.nashcom.de/nshweb/pages/startscript.htm) scripts from Daniel Nashed to start your domino servers and setup your services. It‘s free, you just have to reqeust it from him. This script takes care of all prerequisits and also handles the ulimits.

Once installed it is a no-brainer and it even gives you a domino console via ssh in every shell session.

Great stuff...